# Need to set API data to bar charts in flutter

Tags: json, rest, flutter, bar-chart

I have an API which calls out for a specific user and returns a data set. I need to set these data to bar charts upon their category . Bar chart for Macro category data and bar chart for Micro category data.

***Here is the API response I get***

```
{
  "id": 17,
  "activity_level_name": "Low Activity (<1hr/day)",
  "age": 2,
  "birth_day": "12",
  "birth_month": "12",
  "birth_year": "2018",
  "breed_name": "Australian Kelpie",
  "daily_allowance_guidelines_details": [
    {
      "name": "Muscle Meat",
      "bones": true,
      "percentage": 60
    },
    {
      "name": "Organ Meat",
      "bones": false,
      "percentage": 10
    },
    {
      "name": "Fruit and Veg",
      "bones": false,
      "percentage": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "Bone",
      "bones": true,
      "percentage": 10
    }
  ],
  "eatbone": true,
  "ideal_weight": 12,
  "image": {
    "url": null,
    "thumb": {
      "url": null
    }
  },
  "imperial_weight": 0.38801399999999997,
  "name": "gummy",
  "nutrient_guideline_detail": [
    {
      "name": "Protein",
      "amount": 25.82,
      "unit": "g",
      "imperial_amount": "0.91"
    },
    {
      "name": "Crude fat",
      "amount": 7.92,
      "unit": "g",
      "imperial_amount": "0.28"
    },
    {
      "name": "Calcium/Phosphorus ratio",
      "amount": 1.15,
      "unit": "ratio",
      "imperial_amount": "N/A"
    },
    {
      "name": "Omega-3/6 ratio",
      "amount": 0.14,
      "unit": "ratio",
      "imperial_amount": "N/A"
    },
    {
      "name": "Omega-6",
      "amount": 1.61,
      "unit": "g",
      "imperial_amount": "0.06"
    },
    {
      "name": "Omega-3 excl. ALA and SDA",
      "amount": 0.06,
      "unit": "g",
      "imperial_amount": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "name": "Calcium",
      "amount": 0.72,
      "unit": "g",
      "imperial_amount": "0.03"
    },
    {
      "name": "Phosphorus",
      "amount": 0.57,
      "unit": "g",
      "imperial_amount": "0.02"
    },
    {
      "name": "Potassium",
      "amount": 0.86,
      "unit": "g",
      "imperial_amount": "0.03"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sodium (Na)",
      "amount": 0.11,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000004048114788"
    },
    {
      "name": "Magnesium",
      "amount": 0.09,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000003036086091"
    },
    {
      "name": "Iron",
      "amount": 5.74,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.0002024057394"
    },
    {
      "name": "Copper",
      "amount": 1.05,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.0000370402503102"
    },
    {
      "name": "Manganese",
      "amount": 0.72,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000025300717425"
    },
    {
      "name": "Zinc (Zn)",
      "amount": 11.48,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.0004048114788"
    },
    {
      "name": "Iodine",
      "amount": 143.45,
      "unit": "mcg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000005060143485"
    },
    {
      "name": "Selenium",
      "amount": 0.05,
      "unit": "mcg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.0000000016192459152"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vitamin A",
      "amount": 215.18,
      "unit": "mcg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.0000075902152275"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vitamin D",
      "amount": 1.78,
      "unit": "mcg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000000062745779214"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vitamin E",
      "amount": 6.46,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000227706456825"
    },
    {
      "name": "Thiamin (B1)",
      "amount": 0.32,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000011334721406400002024057394"
    },
    {
      "name": "Riboflavin (B2)",
      "amount": 0.75,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000026312746122"
    },
    {
      "name": "Niacin (B3)",
      "amount": 1.95,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.000068817951396"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pantothenic acid (B5)",
      "amount": 1.72,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.00006072172182"
    },
    {
      "name": "Folate",
      "amount": 30.99,
      "unit": "mcg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.00000109299099276"
    },
    {
      "name": "Choline",
      "amount": 195.1,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.0068817951396"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vitamin C",
      "amount": 0,
      "unit": "mg",
      "imperial_amount": "0.0"
    }
  ],
  "pet_life_stage_name": null,
  "sex": "male",
  "total_daily_calories": "573.81",
  "weight": 11
}
```

how can I retrieve these data and bind them to  bar charts. So far I have implemented this chatline

```
 child: Column(
        ...
        children: [
          ChartLine(title: 'Fat', number: 1800, rate: 1),
        ....
```

***The ChartLine Class***

```
class ChartLine extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChartLine({
    Key key,
    @required this.rate,
    @required this.title,
    this.number,
  })  : assert(title != null),
        assert(rate != null),
        assert(rate > 0),
        assert(rate <= 1),
        super(key: key);

  final double rate;
  final String title;
  final int number;

  final int _baseDurationMs = 1000;
  final double _maxElementWidth = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ControlledAnimation(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: (rate * _baseDurationMs).round()),
        tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: rate),
        builder: (context, animatedHeight) {
          return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            final lineWidget = constraints.maxWidth * animatedHeight;
            // ignore: deprecated_member_use
            return
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:8.0),
                child:
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: lineWidget),
                      child: IntrinsicWidth(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              title,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                              ),
                            ),
                            if (number != null)
                              Text(
                                number.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                                ),
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Color(0xFF32BEFA),
                      height: 24,
                      width: lineWidget,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
          });
        });
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me to achieve this? a code example would do much help. Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FutureBuilder. Create a model and json mapper for a `nutrient_guideline`, wrap your chart with a FutureBuilder and assign a future function that returns list of mapped nutrient_guidelines from the api response data. With this you can access the values in your chart and bind them however you want. You can also refresh or update your chart easily with this. You can check out FutureBuilder class documentation here [FutureBuilder Class Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_for_web/latest/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: could you please provide me with a simple code example upon my question ? would be really helpful.